# fetch data between related tables and pass it to a single array - symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I have two tables with a relationship existing between two tables users and uploads

```
users

id | name | username
1  | xy1  | foo
2  | xy2  | bah

uploads

id | description | title | userfk
1  |  aaa        | x1    |  1
2  |  bbb       | x2    |  2
```

the result the doctrine query should look like

```
1 xy1 foo aaa x1     as a first output result
2 xy2 bah bbb x2     as a second result
```

currently doing this but dont know how to fetch the result simultaneosly from the two tables

```
$restresults = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MyBundle:Uploads')->findBy(['active' => true], ['id' => 'DESC']);
```

kindly assist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have done exactly everything what you need.You are getting all rows from uploads repository where also have upload user informations.and you also serialising all in a array.

Just add some more index inside your `serializeUploads(Uploads $uploads)` function as,

```
private function serializeUploads(Uploads $uploads) {
        return array(
            'description' => $uploads->getDescription(),
            'title' => $uploads->getTitle(),
            'id' => $uploads->getId(),
            'user'=>$uploads->getUserfk()->getName()

        );
    }
```

Please let me know if you are expecting this results or not.Thank you.

Comment: What is the method to get name of user in Users entity's.you should use that method instead of getName()  . if you have entity relation with user object than $uploads->getUserfk() will return the user object so now u can use your method to get name of this  user object.otherwise $uploads->getUserfk() will return you the id (int) but if you have entity relation than it will be easier to get the value of name property.